# Erro de compilação "A new expression requires () or [] after type"

Tags: unity3d

Estou criando um jogo em base de um video no youtube... E neste video tem um link para o site com os códigos, eu copiei os códigos e colei exatamente como tava pra depois modificar e fazer da minha forma... Mas está dando uns erros na Unity que não consigo resolver!

O erro ocorre no código da classe `Dinheiro`:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class Dinheiro : MonoBehaviour {

public Vector2 velocity = new Vector2(0, -4);
public Vector3 velocity3D = new Vector3(0, -4, 0);
public float range = 4;

// Use this for initialization
void Start () {

    //rigidbody2D.velocity = velocity;
    transform.position = new Vector3(transform.position.x – range * Random.value, transform.position.y , transform.position.z);

}



// Update is called once per frame
void Update () {
    transform.position += velocity3D * Time.deltaTime;
}

}
```

A mensagem de erro é **`A new expression requires () or [] after type`** e o compilador indica a linha 14, onde há o comando `transform.position = new Vector3(...`, conforme ilustrado a seguir:

[image: Codigos]

Comment: Aparentemente não há nada errado na linha 14 da classe `Dinheiro` (com o comando `transform.position = new Vector3...`). Você tem certeza que é esse o código sendo usado pelo seu projeto na Unity?

Comment: sim, tenho certeza! Eu tmb n vi nada de errado, estranhei mto!

Comment: Ok. Se você zipar o seu projeto e colocar em algum lugar pra eu baixar, posso testar por aqui na minha Unity. Ah, e da próxima vez que abrir uma pergunta procure ser mais objetivo e completo. Você poderia ter colocado apenas o código da classe `Dinheiro`, indicado a linha onde potencialmente está o problema (pois o compilador te indica isso). Também evite títulos pouco explicativos (como o que usou). Assim você provavelmente não teria recebido os votos negativos que recebeu. :)

Comment: Ok, muito obrigado pelas dicas! Coloquei no DropBox: https://www.dropbox.com/s/h93lj2j700t74ui/Unity2D.zip?dl=0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depois de efetuar alguns testes, o problema parece ser relacionado aos caracteres utilizados no código.

Como você mesmo disse, vocÊ copiou o código de uma página na Web e colou diretamente no editor da Unity. Feito isso, o texto foi colado *tal como formatado na página* (isto é, utilizando caracteres codificados em Unicode ao invés de ANSI). Por exemplo, um hifen mais longo ao invés do sinal de subtração é o que causou o erro apontado na questão.

Esse tipo de erro é mais facilmente observável nas strings em que o código colado é esse (que são outros erros que você ia obter se corrigisse esse primeiro):

```
InvokeRepeating(“CreateObstacle”, 1f, 1.5f); // em Generate.cs
```

ao invés de ser assim (usando a aspas *normais*, como digitada diretamente por meio do teclado):

```
InvokeRepeating("CreateObstacle", 1f, 1.5f);
```

Esse "problema" decorre provavelmente da característica do editor da Unity de colar texto formatado (tipo [RTF](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rich_Text_Format)). Não sei se isso pode ou não ser considerado um bug da ferramenta, mas provavelmente causa esse tipo de dificuldades com frequência. :)

Comment: Muito obrigado!! Deu certo!! :D Vc é 10

Comment: Por nada. :) Perguntas de Unity são muito bem vindas (ao menos por mim! hehehe). Mas não se esqueça de caprichar um pouco mais na pergunta da próxima vez, ok? Não é só um puxão de orelha (e não leve a mal, por favor), mas é que perguntas bem construídas certamente facilitam um bocado que os autores obtenham respostas melhores (e mais rapidamente).